# Toaster not importing

Tags: reactjs

In my react app I am trying to import `<Toaster>` but I'm getting the error:

```
export 'Toaster' (imported as 'Toaster') was not found in './ui'.
```

I don't understand why.

**Toaster.js**

```
function Toaster(props) {
   return (
      <div>
      </div>
   )
}

export default Toaster;
```

**app.js**

```
import {Toaster} from './ui';
<Toaster toasts={['toast1', 'toast2']} />
```

Inside `ui` folder on `index.js`:

```
import Toast from './Toaster';

export {
  Toast
}
```

Comment: This is not how you should post your code. It is poorly formatted and not separated correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ui.js` you've exported something you've named `Toast` but then try to import something called `Toaster` which of course doesn't exist. Instead try `import { Toast } from './ui'`.

Otherwise you can name it as you expect it to be:

```
import Toaster from './Toaster';

export {
  Toaster
}
```

This is called a named export and you have to import it exactly as you've written it. Only with `default` export can you name it what you like, or if you explicitly rename the import with `import { Toast as WhateverYouWant } from './ui'`

Answer (score 0):

import Toaster like below:

```
import Toaster from './ui';
```

This is beacause Toaster was exported as default.

Comment: it did not work

Comment: @siddhantkumar what error did you get? Import error or something else?

Comment: export 'default' (imported as 'Toaster') was not found in './ui' (possible exports: Button, Field, Message, Modal, Toast)

Comment: In which file is the Toaster component declared and exported from?

Comment: Does your "ui" folder have an index.js file... Is that file importing and exporting Toaster ??

Answer (score 0):

inside ui folder in index.js page

```
import Toaster from './Toaster';
```